# How to bootstrap spring cloud config server with Private Github repository?

Tags: spring, git, ssh, cloud, config

I need to connect spring cloud server to my private github repository. I get an error "Reason: Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key"

Steps:

- First I create by git bash a public and private key.
- Then I deploy the public key under github config repository (where i put configuration files == config-repo)
- Finally this is my application.yml

```
spring:
   cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@github.com:[repository]/config-repo.git
          searchPaths: '{application}'
          hostKey: someHostKey
          hostKeyAlgorithm: ssh-rsa
          ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
          privateKey: |
                      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                      [...]
                      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Could you help me to startup my server ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: fix this issue. Do not create ssh key under windows with git bash. I have to generate ssh key on linux OS (like coreOS). And it's done: private key is now valid

Comment: You should provide your comment as your solution. I also had the same problem. Your comment is the working solution. Still, I'm not sure why the ssh key generated on windows git bash is not working.

Comment: Generating the key pair with Linux worked for me as well

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same ... I was generating my keys with Linux ssh-keygen

I generated keys and not more 
 *Reason: Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key*
error

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the key-pair in the PEM format. This was the default a while back, but these days you have to specify it when you invoke `ssh-keygen`.

An example:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "user@example.com"
```

The private key you get out then starts with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved my issue with adding the passphrase (the one us) solve my issue.

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.passphrase=yourPassphrase
```

PS: I am using .properties instead of .yml.